# Using QueryString to display Details

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have a search that displays results. The results are of two types Items and Contacts. They are displayed under one template in a ListView using  `.Union()`. I have two pages ContactDetails.aspx and ItemDetails.aspx.

Below is a example of my `<ItemTemplate>`. This just shows the Contact part. How would I change those links based on whether it is a Item or Contact and change the URL based on that?

This is the URL I would need to use for Items `~/LoggedIn/ItemDetails.aspx?ItemID={0}`

```
              <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="link"
                        Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'
                       NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("ID", "~/LoggedIn/ContactDetails.aspx?ContactID={0}")                             %>' />
                    <br />

                    <ul>

                        <li>
                            <span><b>Identity:</b><%#Eval("ID") %></span></li>


                        <li><span><b>Phone:</b><%#Eval("Phone") %></span></li>

                    </ul>

                                    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" CssClass="btn"  ID="ConUpdateLink"
                        Text='Update'
                        NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("ID", "~/Admin/UpdateContact.aspx?ContactID={0}") %>' />                        

                </ItemTemplate>
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @ean5533 How would I change those links based on whether it is a Item or Contact and change the URL based on that.

Comment: @jackncoke: Basically I can see two links on your code. What you expect? do you need to pass somthing along with the `contactId`??

Comment: @huMptyduMpty ContactID and ItemID become ID when they are displayed in the listview template.  Now that they are one in the same i am having a issue of directing them to proper details page.  My Details pages grab the querystring.  So i guess what i am trying to expect is that when i click on a item it goes to ItemDetails and when i click on a Contact it goes to ContactDetails.

Comment: @jackncoke: How you determine whether its a `itemid` or `contactid` ??

Comment: @huMptyduMpty That was the heart of the question! Sorry for poor explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it:

```
    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" CssClass="btn"  ID="ConUpdateLink"
        Text='Update' 
        NavigateUrl='<%# GetValidUrl((string)Eval("ID")) %>' />
```

Then in the code behind:

```
    public string GetValidUrl(string id)
    {
        string ret = string.Empty;
        if (/*it is item id*/)
        {
            ret = string.Format("~/Admin/UpdateContact.aspx?ContactID={0}", id);
        }
        else if (/*it is contact id*/)
        {
            ret = string.Format("~/LoggedIn/ItemDetails.aspx?ItemID={0}", id);
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

you need to add the part for checking types by id, or pass other value that can be used for this purpose.